# USB-hosted distro with selective persistence

Tags: distribution-choice, distributions, tails-os

I really like Tails. Specifically, I like that I start with a fresh, clean OS each time I boot up from USB and that it let's me choose what persists, so that I can have software that persists, but everything else – like user files – do not. This is exactly what I want. That is to say, I'm an atypical Tails user, as privacy isn't my key concern, rather I want selective persistence between boots.

The problem I have then is that everything is locked down so tight that, for example, I cannot use melpa when running Emacs because this seems to be blocked by Tails. (I fully realise that Tails is doing this for good reason and that I'm using Tails "off-label" then complaining about it!)

---

**My question then:** is there another USB-hosted distro that has the same style of selective persistence, but is not so tightly locked down? (Or, alternatively, is there a way loosen Tails restrictions?)

PS I am aware of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14226/which-live-usb-distribution-offers-selective-persistence), but it is ten years old now and presumably a lot has happened between now and then.

Answer (score 1):

[Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) is a secure OS, too, but I has different concepts:
You have "*Disposable Virtual Machines*" (DVMs) that are destroyed after use.
Basically the DVMs are less restricted than Tails is, but you'll have to save files you want to keep manually (e.g. send them to some external media or to another VM that is not disposable).
The system disk is completely encrypted via LUKS, and VMs get their disks from thinly provisioned Logical Volumes.

Qubes-OS has to be installed, and while it works on an USB stick, the nature of running multiple VMs off the stick will make it rather slow.
So it's better to use an external SSD or a real hard disk.
Requiring at least 8GB of RAM (more is highly preferrable) shouldn't be an issue today, and the disk space it needs starts at about 64GB.

However Qubes-OS may be harder to use than Tails OS.
You cannot have both: Ease of use and security.

Regarding the security of Tails OS:
I think most of the restrictions are implemented via [AppArmor](https://www.apparmor.net/), so you might try to disable it (as `root`user).
But you should know what you are doing.